# Gridview out of range exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using gridview to represent data in asp.net, inside my code I found

```
dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Sunday"]=((TextBox(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text;
```

it throw `out of range exception`.

I think the problem in (controls) but I do not know how to solve it, so could you please help me?

Comment: Have you debugged and ensured all the indexes you are trying to get actually exist?  Its bound to be something either in your data grid or the text box.

Comment: So one of your arrays contains less items then you think. Check it under debugger. This is the only we can say by this code string.

Comment: Try to use debug mode..
It means that some of your objects are trying to refer to index which is "out of range"

Comment: Are you sure that you actually have at least 5 cells in a row?

Comment: never a good idea to use magic number in the index of array without properly checking it first.

Comment: I have 9 cells in the gridview. I am generate the cells and its column dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether or not the collections of things you're trying to access elements of by index actually have at least the number of items expected. You can do that by checking the `Length`, or `Count` property (depending on the type, e.g. array or a list).

This error could be thrown anywhere you use the access-by-index, so conditionalise use of each of these. You can then do something according to what you then know, such as ask the user for valid input etc.

Comment: I checked it, i found it zero. maybe because i am fill the gridview using table dynamically. so how can I read the new value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking how many cells your row have. The count is zero-based so if you want to get the control on cell #4, you need to subtract it by 1, so:

```
((TextBox(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
```

Also check if you have a control on that cell.

Comment: How can I check if I have a control on this cell?

Comment: I checked it, i found it zero. maybe because i am fill the gridview using table dynamically.